# Exist a constant $C$ satisfies $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon\leq |x|\leq\pi-\varepsilon}|\frac{\sin (n+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}|dx<C?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Here is my idea:
 $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon\leq |x|\leq\pi-\varepsilon}\Bigg|\frac{\sin (n+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}\Bigg|dx$$

can be written this
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\Bigg|\frac{\sin (n+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}\Bigg|dx&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\Bigg|\frac{\sin nx\cos\frac{x}{2}+\cos nx\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\sin x/2}\Bigg|dx\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\Bigg|\frac{\sin nx\cos \frac{x}{2}}{\sin x/2}+\cos nx\Bigg|dx\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\Bigg|\frac{\sin nx\cos \frac{x}{2}}{\sin x/2}\Bigg|dx+\pi\\
\end{align*}

This is all what I can do, and I still can not find a constant $C$ independent of $n$ such that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\Bigg|\frac{\sin (n+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}\Bigg|dx\leq C.
$$
So my method might be wrong.

Comment: The result you're trying to prove does not hold. You have $$\int_0^\pi \left\lvert \frac{\sin (n+1/2)x}{\sin x/2}\right\rvert\,dx = K\cdot \log n + O(1),$$ where the constant $K$ is $2/\pi^2$ or so [I never can remember the exact constants]. The integral is up to constant factors the $L^1$ norm of the Dirichlet kernel.

Comment: @DanielFischer It is a pity... Could you please tell me where do you find this result?

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) has the statement that the norm is of the order of $\log n$, Rudin (Real and Complex Analysis, section 5.11) has a more precise estimate.